# Tikz + breqn: Compiling never finishes with |-Symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, debugging, breqn

I just occurred a strange error in tikz. The following MWE never finishes on my machine (MikTeX, breqn Version 0.98e, tikz Version 3.0.1a):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
    Some text
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) node {$|x|$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Questions:

- Why does this happen? (or is it just my configuration?)
- How can I avoid it? `\|` works fine, but that results in a double line and is not what I want.

Of course I could just remove `breqn` (then it compiles fine), but I'd like to avoid that since I use it often in my document.

This is the end of the produced log file:

```
\eq@hshift=\dimen204
\eq@given@sidespace=\dimen205
\mathindent=\dimen206
\eq@final@linecount=\count144
\eq@wdR=\dimen207
\EQ@continue=\toks29
\lr@level=\count145
\GRP@queue=\toks30
\c@parentequation=\count146
\GRP@box=\box56
\GRP@wholebox=\box57
\darraycolsep=\skip58
\cur@row=\count147
\cur@col=\co
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `breqn` the `|` is made math active, which means that it is treated as a macro in math mode.

However, `tikz` seizes the initiative as well and inside a `tikzpicture` it redefines the active `|` to be `\tikz@nonactivebar`, which essentially is the non active `|`; but `|` is *math active* and we're in math mode, so it acts again as an active character, which translates to `\tikz@nonactivebar`…

Infinite loop, sorry.

You can cure the specific issue by loading `amsmath` and using `\lvert x\rvert` instead of `|x|` (which is conceptually better, by the way). There are possibly other characters that produce the issue.

A (not widely tested) workaround for characters for which no alias is available like for `|`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{breqn}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\aliasmathchar}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\@sym##1##2##3##4{"##2##3##4}%
  \@namedef{math_char:NNn}{}%
  \lccode`~=`#2 \lowercase{\global\mathchardef#1=~}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\aliasmathchar\semicolon{;}\show\semicolon

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node {$\lvert x\semicolon\rvert$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, good explanation! Is there a list of those characters, that might produce such issues?

Comment: @jaytar I don't know. Sorry, but I think that `breqn` is just a good proof of concept, not to be used in production.

Comment: Semicolon (:) also produces the same type of error.

Comment: @YauhenYakimenka I provided a possible workaround for providing aliases to characters that show bad behavior. But I stand on my position: `breqn` is a proof of concept not to be used in production.

Comment: I added note on semicolon just for the record. As to my document, I also deleted breqn usage.